# How do I branch?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=azure-devops

I have a brand new project in Azure DevOps.  There's nothing in it yet, but I want to set up the branches to model the Servicing, Hotfix, Release isolation strategy from the link above.

To do this, I need a branch, and a branch of a branch.

When I right click my project and say "Branch", it prompts for a Target. 
This is where everything I try does not work.

First thing I tried was to use $/Master/HotFix.  This returns an error "The target item $/Master/HotFix cannot be under the source item $/Master.

Then, I tried just $/Master-HotFix and get an error "Source control must branch into an existing team project.  Master-HotFix is not a team project"

So, I went to Azure DevOps and I created a new project called Master-HotFix.  I mapped it in Visual Studio, and tried again.  This time, I got the error "Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/Master-HotFix. Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project.

Surely making a branch isn't this difficult?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, seems you get promoted a kind of below dialog

[image: TFS branch popup]

> I have a brand new project in Azure DevOps. There's nothing in it yet

You are trying to **branch a Team Project rather than a folder containing your code**.

You should first have your code in a folder, say "Master", under the "$/TeamProject/" folder. You can then branch "$/TeamProject/Master" to "$/TeamProject/Master/child".

If you have dumped all of your code into the root of your team project then you will need to move it into a folder first, then branch that folder.

**warning:** You can create a new team project that is a branch of this one, giving you "$/Master". However this method is a terrible idea and will lead to pain and suffering

For more details please refer our official tutorial:

1. [Convert a Folder to a Branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=azure-devops#convert-a-folder-to-a-branch)
2. [Branch a folder or file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=azure-devops#branch-a-branch)

Comment: Thank you.  It was the step of adding a folder to the project, then converting that to a branch that was confusing.  It is not intuitive.  If I could suggest some edits to the documentation to reflect simplifying things? Create a step by step "How To" kind of document.  1: Create a project. 2: Add a folder named Master (Trunk, or whatever). 3: Convert the folder to a branch.  4: THEN branch from there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to branch in TFVC you first need to create you master/MAIN branch as a folder.  Then you check that folder in.  After you can convert it to a branch from the branch menu.  After that you'll be able to branch off that master/MAIN branch and create the structure you are trying to do.

Cheers,
ET